# View for having a group of three or more Views, show only one view each time

Tags: android, view

Are there any View or way in android for being able to group three or more views but only showing one of them each time?

I´ve seen that android has **ViewSwitcher** but it *only allows to swap between two views*. If you add more than two then an exception is thrown.

Also there is a view called **ViewStub** but *it doesn´t swap views*, only inflate them when you need them. I´d like to be able to swap between views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget you are looking for is the [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html).

Comment: Yes, that view is the one I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ViewPager.

Refer this for [example](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)